# How to change search result highlight in vi?

Tags: ssh, vim, vi

The scenario: I log on a server using ssh, and search for keywords in a log file using `vi`.

The problem: at the moment, the results of a search is only highlighted by a cursor `_` below the searched word, which is not very easy to find on a screen of log messages.

The question: how can I change the highlighting of the search results to something more noticeable? e.g. different background and foreground colors on the whole word.

Comment: previously I used `set cursorline` to help finding the search result. But `set hlsearch` works better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch to vim, and use `:set hlsearch`

You can then use `:highlight Search ctermfg=yellow` to customize; where:

- `cterm` is for formating
- `ctermfg` is for foreground color
- `ctermbg` is for background color

<sup>see `:help highlight` [link](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3ahighlight)</sup>

You can then use `:noh` to temporarily hide the last search highlight.

Comment: You can add the first two settings to your `~/.vimrc`, without the leading `:`. You can also bind `:noh` to a key, for ease of use.

Answer (score 1):

Also, FYI, in GUI version of Vim:

- `gui` is for formatting (as opposite of `cterm`)
- `guifg` is for foreground color (as opposite of `ctermfg`)
- `guibg` is for background color (as opposite of `ctermbg`)